# Custom field in IDBC writer?

Tags: tinylog

I have a application where I am using logging for the app, but I also want to do an audit log to the sql server. I was going to use tagging to specify what I want to log to the sql server, but how do I add a custom column / field to specify the user of said log entry? I have columns for timestamp, tag, level and message but I also have a column for user. what do I put into the "writer.field.user = ???" to specify what I want that column to have? This would be the same value for each instance and duration of the app when they log in. I have TinyLog v2.6.2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case, I suggest to use [context values](https://tinylog.org/v2/logging/#context-values) for your custom fields. For example, when the user logs in, you can store the user name via `ThreadContext.put("user", name)`.

Afterwards, all log entries, which are issued by the same thread or of one of its child thread, will be enriched by the stored context values. You can use the placeholder `{context: key}` for assigning context value to SQL table fields. If you have stored the user name with the key `user` in the thread context, you can assign it via `writer.field.user = {context: user}"`.

If you use a thread pool or if you reuse threads for different users, you have to take care of clearing the thread context before reusing a thread.

Comment: Thank you, I did not see what in the documentation right away. That would work.